# Node.js server not connectong from other hosts

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sockets, socket.io

So I use node.js socket server in my webpage, at localhost everything is OK. 
I connect to server like this `socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {port: 3000, transports: ["websocket"]});`

Then I wanted to put my webpage online, I put it like virtual host in apache with port 8080 and in router forwarded both ports 8080 and 3000.

But other people cant connect. I replaced localhost with my IP that I access to webpage from browser but nothing. Whats wrong?

Comment: What port is your server listening on? Can you post the code for the server?

Comment: `socket = io.listen(3000);`  I listen and connect to port 3000